# Was the "Khyber Dam" from the 2012 BBC TV show 'Hunted' a real dam?

Tags: hunted

Is the "Khyber Dam" from the 2012 BBC TV show 'Hunted' a dam in real life?

Comment: Is "Hunted" a fantasy or science fiction show?

Comment: @AndresF. Based on its Wikipedia page, it doesn't look like it.  It's a spy show set in present day, nothing seems to be fantastical.

Comment: That's correct, it is not sci fi or fantasy. It's more like a crime drama. A totally awesome crime drama. Kind of like Spooks, at least, in the same sort of genre. There is nothing supernatural in the show. Too bad it only lasted one season because it was one of my favorite shows!

Comment: p.s. it may not be "fantastical", but it is definitely fantastic!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the dam referenced in the show does not (currently) exist, at least not under the name that was used (the "Upper Khyber Dam"), but a similar dam project could easily exist in the claimed area.

Khyber is not the name of a river in Pakistan, it's the name of an entire region, so naming the dam after it wouldn't make much sense (like calling something the "Whales Dam" or the "Texas Dam".) However, the Khyber Pakhtunkhwa province in Pakistan **is** home to several large rivers that are prone to flooding. The Indus river, for example, famously flooded in 2010 and caused severe damage in the Khyber region. The Jhelum river is also noted for repeatedly flooding and washing out major bridges in the area.

Most likely, however, the dam in the show would be one on the [Kunhar River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunhar_River), which passes near or through several well-populated villages in the upper Khyber region. It flows down from the mountains in the upper part of the Khyber province, growing and shrinking seasonally as the glaciers that feed it freeze and melt.

Pakistan is a growing country with ever-increasing power needs, so it not be uncommon to find ongoing or proposed dam projects on any of these rivers as a means of providing hydroelectric power to the surrounding region.